# codeigniter The requested URL /User was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i Have codeigniter 3.0.1 installed in ubuntu 14.04 apache 2.4.7, it was run normally in windows with wamp server but when i move it to the ubuntu server it keep getting that error,the rewrite module already enabled and this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and this is the configuration of config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://assets1.uofk.edu';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

this is routes.php configuration:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'User';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Also i considered the ubuntu case sensitive matter of naming model but still getting not found error..please help

Comment: With your current config you need to include index.php in your homepage URL like this http://assets1.uofk.edu/index.php/user, is that the address giving you a 404?

Comment: yes when i include index.php it redirects to assets1.uofk.edu/User and give same error

Comment: Try default controller `$route['default_controller'] = 'user';` lower case on route. Make sure though the filename and class name **User.php** and `class User extends CI_Controller {}` Where the first letter is only the one that is uppercase on file and class name

Comment: Base url end with `/` like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://assets1.uofk.edu/';`

Comment: I think AUTO has also been removed for uri_protocol in codeigniter 3 versions use REQUEST_URI

Comment: I tried all this but no new, same error, i think the issue in ubuntu 14.04 because the CI works fine in windows wamp server

Answer (score 0):

try check your .htaccess change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and check your config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://assets1.uofk.edu/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and check your controller name must be User.php and on your class must User

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

and this is the configuration of config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'YOUR_URL';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htaccess RewriteRule Examples https://www.brontobytes.com/knowledgebase/149/htaccess-RewriteRule-Examples.html